# Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid address

Tags: web3js

I get a reference to my contract on Rinkeby like this:

```
const MyContract = web3.eth.contract(MyContractABI)
  myContract = MyContract.at(contractAddress)
```

I can call this function fine:

```
myContract.functionOne(addressParamater, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

But when I call :

```
myContract.functionTwo(addressParamater, function(err, res) {
    console.log(res)
  });
```

I get this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): invalid address
```

I'm passing an address as a paramater to both functions, and I know its well formated since when I do this:

```
web3.isAddress(addressParamater);
```

I get `true`

Any idea what could be going on?

Thanks!

Comment: can we have the contract functions implementation by any chance?